# Hangfire Windows service Dashboard

Tags: hangfire

I want to see the dashboard for hang-fire in windows service project.
I saw the solution in [Here](https://brosteins.com/2016/02/14/setting-up-the-hangfire-dashboard-in-a-windows-service/) but I guess it is a bit old 
I don't have StartOptions class. Is there a better documentation on using hangfire dashboard on windows service.

```
 StartOptions options = new StartOptions();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the example you found [here](https://brosteins.com/2016/02/14/setting-up-the-hangfire-dashboard-in-a-windows-service/) and it is actually updated. You probably didn't notice that you need to install first the `Microsoft.Owin.Hosting` before you can use `StartOptions()`.

```
using Hangfire;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;  // --> You need to install this first

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("hangfire");
StartOptions options = new StartOptions();
options.Urls.Add("http://localhost:9095");
options.Urls.Add("http://127.0.0.1:9095");
options.Urls.Add($"http://{Environment.MachineName}:9095");

WebApp.Start<Startup>(options);
```

Nuget Package is `Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Hosting`;

Comment: Anybody on earth know how to make it not self hosting and IIS integrated?!?!?!??!!??!?!!??!?!  Help the uneducated!  My question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387782/need-hangfire-dashboard-iis-integrated

Comment: You cant make a Windows Service run under IIS (w3c) !!!!! - I am trying to split the two however. make the service run to always stay alive but use my web app to have the front end stuff connect to the service - Thats the only way if you want service/web - otherwise its all under web (which has its drawbacks for 24/7 running under IIS)