# Need Hangfire Dashboard IIS Integrated from Console App

Tags: iis, console-application, owin, dashboard, hangfire

I am closely following the HangFire solution from: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Samples/blob/master/Hangfire.WindowsServiceApplication/Program.cs

The solution starts up the HangFire dashboard as a self hosting web site.

[image]

[image]

I need it integrated with IIS, so the dashboard is accessible outside the server.  I don't want to always log into the server, open a browser, and go to local host and some port number.  Help me!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker found the answer.  They used the following website help: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html

[image]

Steps followed:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]